# "undefined method `has_key?' for #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard..."

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant

I'm trying to enable credit card billing in a rails app, and I receive the following error when trying to create the order: `undefined method 'has_key?' for #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard:0x244b3d8>`

The referenced code is the `purchase` method in the order model:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  include ActiveMerchant::Billing

  ...
  def credit_card
    @credit_card ||= ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(   
    :type           => card_type,
    :number         => card_number,
    :month          => card_expires_on.month,
    :year               => card_expires_on.year,
    :first_name => first_name,
    :last_name  => last_name,
    :verification_value  => card_verification
    )
  end

  def purchase

    response = GATEWAY.authorize(price_in_cents, credit_card)
    if response.success?
      GATEWAY.capture(price_in_cents, response.authorization)
      cart.update_attribute(:purchased_at, Time.now)
    else
      raise StandardError, response.message
    end

  end

end
```

I'm using a Paypal Express gateway, for which the Active Merchant library defines `purchase` as follows:

```
  def purchase(money, options = {})
    requires!(options, :token, :payer_id)

    commit 'DoExpressCheckoutPayment', build_sale_or_authorization_request('Sale', money, options)
  end

  private
  def build_get_details_request(token)
    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new :indent => 2
    xml.tag! 'GetExpressCheckoutDetailsReq', 'xmlns' => PAYPAL_NAMESPACE do
      xml.tag! 'GetExpressCheckoutDetailsRequest', 'xmlns:n2' => EBAY_NAMESPACE do
        xml.tag! 'n2:Version', API_VERSION
        xml.tag! 'Token', token
      end
    end

    xml.target!
  end

  def build_sale_or_authorization_request(action, money, options)
    currency_code = options[:currency] || currency(money)

    xml = Builder::XmlMarkup.new :indent => 2
    xml.tag! 'DoExpressCheckoutPaymentReq', 'xmlns' => PAYPAL_NAMESPACE do
      xml.tag! 'DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequest', 'xmlns:n2' => EBAY_NAMESPACE do
        xml.tag! 'n2:Version', API_VERSION
        xml.tag! 'n2:DoExpressCheckoutPaymentRequestDetails' do
          xml.tag! 'n2:PaymentAction', action
          xml.tag! 'n2:Token', options[:token]
          xml.tag! 'n2:PayerID', options[:payer_id]
          xml.tag! 'n2:PaymentDetails' do
            xml.tag! 'n2:OrderTotal', localized_amount(money, currency_code), 'currencyID' => currency_code

            # All of the values must be included together and add up to the order total
            if [:subtotal, :shipping, :handling, :tax].all?{ |o| options.has_key?(o) }
              xml.tag! 'n2:ItemTotal', localized_amount(options[:subtotal], currency_code), 'currencyID' => currency_code
              xml.tag! 'n2:ShippingTotal', localized_amount(options[:shipping], currency_code),'currencyID' => currency_code
              xml.tag! 'n2:HandlingTotal', localized_amount(options[:handling], currency_code),'currencyID' => currency_code
              xml.tag! 'n2:TaxTotal', localized_amount(options[:tax], currency_code), 'currencyID' => currency_code
            end

            xml.tag! 'n2:NotifyURL', options[:notify_url]
            xml.tag! 'n2:ButtonSource', application_id.to_s.slice(0,32) unless application_id.blank?
            xml.tag! 'n2:InvoiceID', options[:order_id]
            xml.tag! 'n2:OrderDescription', options[:description]
          end
        end
      end
    end

    xml.target!
  end
```

It looks like the `credit_card` argument in my order model is being treated as the `options` on which `has_key?` is being called in the Active Merchant library, whose `CreditCard` code doesn't define `has_key?`. I'm using the latest version of Active Merchant.

Any help?

Comment: You're passing through `credit_card` as `options`, which seems wrong to me. Try to find *how* you should be passing `credit_card`. This code is expecting `options` to be a hash.

Comment: Looks as though a bad argument is being supplied to the `purchase` method in the latter code block.  Can you show the code from which you call said method?  (It doesn't look to me as though the first code block calls `purchase` in the latter block.)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some gateways have a different purchase method.

TrustCommerceGateway (code showed on https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant)

```
def purchase(money, creditcard_or_billing_id, options = {})
```

https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/blob/b417c77d435b8d163b6e77588c80ac347cc1316a/lib/active_merchant/billing/gateways/trust_commerce.rb#L164

PayPalExpressCheckoutGateway

```
def purchase(money, options = {})
```

So looks like you have to use PaypalGateway (and not PaypalExpressCheckoutGateway) if you want to use ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard with Paypal